# keyboard shortcut to move from one code block to another in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio 2008 is there a shortcut to move from one block of code to an another block of code directly? Like from one function to say: the beginning of next function.
Currently all I can do is press-press arrow keys.

Edit: I am aware of the Ctrl+] to jump between matching braces but that does not relieve me from multiple up/down presses initially. Also the "Edit.NextMethod" does not work as it is always disabled unless you are editing VB Code (It does not appear to work their either).

Comment: In ReSharper I can use `ALT-DownArrow` and `ALT-UpArrow` to traverse methods.  (can be remapped, of course)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macros is the Solution:
Shipped with VS2008 are sample macros that contain:
**Sample.VSEditor.BeginningOfFunction** - to move to the beginning of a function.
This can be modified to get it to move to the End of the function instead by changing: *CodeElement*.**GetBeginningPoint** to **GetEndPoint**. Next an another user-defined macro: ***NextMethod***() first navigates to the end of current function then finds the next function and finally moves to the beginning of this next function.

Get the Macro: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpide/thread/8c5a2fd2-df25-4196-b211-5da3086f4f3d

Answer (score 12):

If you place your cursor to the **left** of the opening `{`, then `Ctrl`*+*`}` will move you to the end of this method/block/operator

Answer (score 3):

In VB.NET (VS 2010) I wanted to reinstate the old feature of the VB6 editor to navigate to the next and previous methods in a class by hitting the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>DownArrow</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>UpArrow</kbd>.

This was straightforward, by taking the following steps:

- Go to Tools / Options then Environment / Keyboard.
- In the "Show commands containing:" field, type "Edit.NextMethod". This command should then appear in the listbox. Click on it to select it.
- Click on "Press shortcut keys:" to get focus there. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> keys. Check that this key combination now appears in the textbox.
- Look in the textbox below "Shortcut currently used by:". Check that the shortcut currently used by this key combination is not one you want! [unlikely, otherwise you would not be trying to remap the keys]
- Click on the "Assign" button
- Then click on "OK"

You can do the same with `Edit.NextMethod` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>.

Comment: the command to go to the previous method is 'Edit.PreviousMethod'

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl+Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+Down</kbd> will jump to previous/next function.

Comment: By default, Ctrl+Up and Ctrl+Down will scroll the editor up and down without moving the cursor.

Comment: yes does not work in VS2008 and does what @Kirk mentions above.